# Get Unity to read in objects name without the need to hard code

Tags: c#, unity

I'm trying to get away from having to hard code in the names of objects I want my code to use.

For example, I'm use to do it this way:

```
    TextAsset test = new TextAsset();
    test = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("test.txt", typeof(TextAsset));
```

What I want to know, is there a way to have so that when I drag my test.txt file onto my object in Unity, my code automatically gets the name of that object?

I'm wanting to do this so once I write the code, I don't need to back in and change it should I wish re-use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you have a GameObject in the scene you can make a public field of the type TextAsset that can be changed in the editor.

For example, this is an array of TextAssets:

```
class ItemReader : MonoBehavior
{
    public TextAsset[] DataFiles;
}
```

After attaching the containing script to an object in the scene, the result looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cant use Resources.Load without using a string, i dont think that Resources accept any overload arguments.

Have u tried to define a public variable (so you can assign your object via editor) and than use it instead of strings?

Something like:

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System;

public class test : MonoBehaviour {     
public TextAsset tx;


    void Start()    
    {       
     Debug.Log(tx.name);    } 
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not give you the file extension or the full path, but if you are just loading the file in as a text asset this method should totally work.